# SlideMenu Accessible on internal screens iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using [Aryan's Slide Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu#configuring-left-and-right-menu-for-different-viewcontrollers) and it is working perfectly fine. One thing that I need to add here is that the `slide menu` should be accessible in the internal `viewControllers` aswell. when I `push` a `viewController`, the `left bar button item` that is the `slideMenu button` goes away and a back button comes in, Im fine with this too but can I somehow make the slide menu come with the swipe gesture on these inner view controllers aswell ? This same came has been done in the youtube's app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This Method In Your Pushed ViewController

```
- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: this worked but as I wrote I want the back button in the inner viewControllers rather than the slideMenu button. How can i do that ?

Comment: I have no issues if the back button and the menu button both appear on the navigationBar so i used
`self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;`